# Trying to include a library in c++, but not able. I am beginner in c++ so probably some very basic mistake

Tags: c++, include

I am trying to include a c++ library for unlimited size integers. From [web page](https://www.imach.uran.ru/cbignum/Cbignum.txt) it seems to be very good unlimited size integer library for c++ I could find. I am not able to successfully compile my code. I am noob in c++ so probably I am making some very basic mistake, please explain this mistake to me. Or is this library itself not working?
I am trying to include [this](https://www.imach.uran.ru/cbignum/) library, but I am getting errors:
with code:

```
#include <cbignum/Cbignum.h>
#include <cbignum/Cbignumf.h>
#include <cbignum/Exarray.h>
int main(){
    cBigNumber a=cBigNumber(10);
    return 0;}
```

I get errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/suurte_taisrvude_proovid.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `cBigNumber::create(long long)':
[PATH1]/cbignum/Cbignum.h:104: undefined reference to `cBigNumber::_stub'
/usr/bin/ld: [PATH1]/cbignum/Cbignum.h:107: undefined reference to `exmalloc'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/[PATH2]/main.cpp.o: in function `cBigNumber::~cBigNumber()':
[PATH1]/cbignum/Cbignum.h:128: undefined reference to `exfree'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/[PATH2]/main.cpp.o: in function `exblock<long long>::confine(unsigned long)':
[PATH1]/cbignum/Exarray.h:585: undefined reference to `excalcblocksize'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/[PATH2]/main.cpp.o: in function `exblock<long long>::range() const':
[PATH1]/cbignum/Exarray.h:559: undefined reference to `exrange'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/[PATH2]/main.cpp.o: in function `exblock<long long>::reallocate(unsigned long, unsigned long)':
[PATH1]/cbignum/Exarray.h:515: undefined reference to `exnull_c'
/usr/bin/ld: [PATH1]/cbignum/Exarray.h:516: undefined reference to `exrange'
/usr/bin/ld: [PATH1]/cbignum/Exarray.h:539: undefined reference to `exaligned_mrealloc'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

from [this forum post](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=&sl=ru&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.priestt.com%2Ffor%2Fpp%2Fcbignum%2Ftopic_3235.html&sandbox=1) I got idea to add Cbignum.cpp, Cbignumf.cpp, and Exarray.cpp , but with this code:

```
#include <cbignum/Cbignum.h>
#include <cbignum/Cbignumf.h>
#include <cbignum/Exarray.h>
#include <cbignum/Cbignum.cpp>
#include <cbignum/Cbignumf.cpp>
#include <cbignum/Exarray.cpp>
int main(){
    cBigNumber a=cBigNumber(10);
    return 0;}
```

I am getting errors:

```
In file included from [PATH1]/cbignum/Cbignumf.cpp:20,
                 from [PATH3]/main.cpp:45:
[PATH1]/cbignum/Cbignumf.inl: In function ‘void cBigNumberInfo(exptr<long long int>)’:
[PATH1]/cbignum/Cbignumf.inl:145:35: error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘cTTY’ and ‘long long int’)
  145 |     cBigNumberMessages << "... (" << (CBNL)(n1 * sizeof (CBNL)) << " bytes)\n";
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                        |             |
      |                        cTTY          long long int
In file included from [PATH1]/cbignum/Cbignum.h:31,
                 from [PATH3]/main.cpp:41:
[PATH1]/cbignum/Ctty.h:143:14: note: candidate: ‘cTTY& operator<<(cTTY&, long int)’
  143 | inline cTTY& operator << (cTTY& os, long num)
      |              ^~~~~~~~
[PATH1]/cbignum/Ctty.h:148:14: note: candidate: ‘cTTY& operator<<(cTTY&, int)’
  148 | inline cTTY& operator << (cTTY& os, int num)
      |              ^~~~~~~~
[PATH1]/cbignum/Ctty.h:153:14: note: candidate: ‘cTTY& operator<<(cTTY&, short int)’
  153 | inline cTTY& operator << (cTTY& os, short num)
      |              ^~~~~~~~
[PATH1]/cbignum/Ctty.h:158:14: note: candidate: ‘cTTY& operator<<(cTTY&, char)’
  158 | inline cTTY& operator << (cTTY& os, char c)
      |              ^~~~~~~~
In file included from [PATH3]/main.cpp:44:
[PATH1]/cbignum/Cbignum.cpp:1479:7: note: candidate: ‘cTTY& operator<<(cTTY&, const cBigNumber&)’
 1479 | cTTY& operator << (cTTY& os, const cBigNumber& b)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
In file included from [PATH3]/main.cpp:46:
[PATH1]/cbignum/Exarray.cpp: At global scope:
[PATH1]/cbignum/Exarray.cpp:193:17: error: redefinition of ‘size_t exmuladd(size_t, size_t, size_t)’
  193 | size_t  FCDECL  exmuladd (size_t s, size_t n, size_t k)
      |                 ^~~~~~~~
In file included from [PATH1]/cbignum/Cbignum.h:35,
                 from [PATH3]/main.cpp:41:
[PATH1]/cbignum/Exarray.h:228:15: note: ‘size_t exmuladd(size_t, size_t, size_t)’ previously defined here
  228 | inline size_t exmuladd (size_t s, size_t n, size_t k)
      |               ^~~~~~~~
In file included from [PATH3]/main.cpp:46:
[PATH1]/cbignum/Exarray.cpp:198:17: error: redefinition of ‘size_t exmul(size_t, size_t)’
  198 | size_t  FCDECL  exmul (size_t s, size_t n)
      |                 ^~~~~
In file included from [PATH1]/cbignum/Cbignum.h:35,
                 from [PATH3]/main.cpp:41:
[PATH1]/cbignum/Exarray.h:233:15: note: ‘size_t exmul(size_t, size_t)’ previously defined here
  233 | inline size_t exmul (size_t s, size_t n)
      |               ^~~~~
In file included from [PATH3]/main.cpp:46:
[PATH1]/cbignum/Exarray.cpp:203:17: error: redefinition of ‘size_t exadd(size_t, size_t)’
  203 | size_t  FCDECL  exadd (size_t n, size_t k)
      |                 ^~~~~
In file included from [PATH1]/cbignum/Cbignum.h:35,
                 from [PATH3]/main.cpp:41:
[PATH1]/cbignum/Exarray.h:238:15: note: ‘size_t exadd(size_t, size_t)’ previously defined here
  238 | inline size_t exadd (size_t n, size_t k)
      |               ^~~~~
In file included from [PATH3]/main.cpp:46:
[PATH1]/cbignum/Exarray.cpp:208:17: error: redefinition of ‘size_t exchkadd(size_t, size_t, size_t)’
  208 | size_t  FCDECL  exchkadd (size_t n, size_t k, size_t max)
      |                 ^~~~~~~~
In file included from [PATH1]/cbignum/Cbignum.h:35,
                 from [PATH3]/main.cpp:41:
[PATH1]/cbignum/Exarray.h:243:15: note: ‘size_t exchkadd(size_t, size_t, size_t)’ previously defined here
  243 | inline size_t exchkadd (size_t n, size_t k, size_t max)
      |               ^~~~~~~~
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/[PATH2]/build.make:82: CMakeFiles/[PATH2]/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:95: CMakeFiles/[PATH2]/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:102: CMakeFiles/[PATH2]/rule] Error 2
```

Definition of CBNL:

```
#ifndef CBNL
#ifdef  __cplusplus
#if     __cplusplus >= 201103L
#warning "newer standard: long long"
#define CBNL long long
#define CBNL_MIN    LLONG_MIN
#define CBNL_MAX    LLONG_MAX
#define UCBNL_MAX   ULLONG_MAX
#include "Cbnl.inl"
#endif
#endif
#endif

#ifndef CBNL
#warning "older standard: long"
#define CBNL long
#define CBNL_MIN    LONG_MIN
#define CBNL_MAX    LONG_MAX
#define UCBNL_MAX   ULONG_MAX
#include "Cbnl.inl"
#endif
```

Comment: `.cpp` files are not supposed to be `#include`-d.  They are supposed to be compiled separately, and the linker links the compiled code together to create the final program.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, Could I be able to use this library if I compiled these separately or this is just a style issue?

Comment: Are you familiar with how to build a multi-module C++ program?  You're supposed to build each source file separately, and then tell the linker to link all of the compiled source files.  The IDE you're using (if you're using one) would do this by you specifying the files in a project.  If you're compiling on the command-line, then the command-line options would be used to compile several files and link them.

Comment: I am using Clion.

Comment: Typically a library will not consist of a single source file, but multiple source files some of which will provide dependencies for the library functions.

Comment: @MarkRansom, yes I downloaded many files. Just what I should do to use this libary?

Comment: Either there should have been instructions along with the library files, or they expect you to already know how to build a library.

Comment: @MarkRansom, I did not find instructions to include this library. if I included gmp by #include <gmpxx.h> I did not manually build anythig separately. Why do I have to do this to include this libary?

Comment: Section 3, Instructions, in the linked text document was quite enlightening. Are you sure you followed all of the steps? The most relevant seems to be step 2 *Include to the project the following files : [list]*I don't know CLion worth beans, but this may be as easy as right-click and add to project.

Comment: I should probably edit CMakeList.txt and change function's target_link_libraries arguments or function's add_executable arguments to include these files to project, but I do not know which one of these and which argument I should give them.

Comment: @user4581301 I think I did that, but I still get the second errors in my post. These errors seem to be related to something else.

Comment: The first bit's a pretty good error message. I'm not sure what the context around it is, but the message is saying `operator <<` will take just about any integer type EXCEPT a `long long`, and  `CBNL` ultimately winds up at `long long`. Could be a mistake in a typedef somewhere, but you should be able to hack-fix it , assuming that's in your code, with `(long)(n1 * sizeof (long)`

Comment: @user4581301 No, ti is in libraris code.

Comment: @user4581301, Does this mean the library is not working or it is written in some other version of c++

Comment: CLion probably has a tool that will allow you to quickly find where `CBNL` Is defined. Add the definition to the question.

Comment: @user4581301, I added the definition to question.

Comment: `#if     __cplusplus >= 201103L` suggests that you want to compile for C++11 or a more recent standard; otherwise, the compiler uses `#define CBNL long` and the code fails. On the command line that would be adding the `-std=c++11` option. CLion will have the ability to set the Standard revision somewhere in the build settings dialog pages. I don't know where, but you can probably find the option with a quick websearch. This also suggests that your compiler is old. Any compiler released in the last 5 years-or-so will default to at least C++11.

Comment: It goes into "#if     __cplusplus >= 201103L", I know it because I added "#warning "newer standard: long long" into library source code.

Comment: I got it to compile this library by commenting out CBNL definition for newer versions and forcing it to use older version's definition, but I do not know if I broke something in library by doing that.

Comment: Odd. The older version's definition looks to be the broken one.